# bad screen distance

Tags: linux, wxpython, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to obtain an figure object (using matplotlib), inside a wxpython application. I don't need to plot (or see) the figure, because I would want only to save it in a png file.

When I do it using Windows XP, it is all okay, if I do it outside the wxpython application, for example inside sphinx documentation, it's all okay again.
But If I do it inside my wxpython application... something goes wrong and it raises this:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "320.0"
```

Has someone any idea about?

Comment: I suggest replacing the [tcl] tag with [tkinter]

Comment: Looks like it's looking for an integer that it can interpret as a count of pixels. But that's just the immediate diagnosis, and not the real problem. Is there some stack trace that says just where this is bubbling up from? (Why is a wxpython application poking into tkinter?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to use wxPython and getting tkinter errors, you probably haven't told matplotlib to use wx.  This can either be done in the matplotlibrc file, or in the program.  Instructions are [here](http://matplotlib.github.com/faq/installing_faq.html#what-is-a-backend).

Comment: great,you are right. I modified the $HOME/.matplotlib/matplotlib.rc changing `backend      : TKAgg` to `backend      : WXAgg`. In these day I'm going to do some experiments on this rc file. Thanks a lot.